# System restarts whenever ethernet cable is connected (and system is not connected to power source)

Tags: 14.04, ati, power-management, ethernet

I have a strange problem with my Ubuntu 14.04 system.

If my laptop is not connected to a power source, and I plug in my ethernet cable, the system restarts.

It's an  AMD processor with ATI radeon graphics.

I have a dual boot system with Windows8, and no such issue is encountered while in Windows.
I had Ubuntu 13.10 prior to 14.04 and did not face such a problem.

Any idea what could be causing this issue?